# Publish of the website in visual studio using "Release" mode

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, publish, release-mode

I have a Library Project (C#) with MVC website. In this project I'm adding some values to my database. When I publish this website using "Release" mode, it doesn't work correctly in IIS. A connection to my database doesn't work and I can't add any values to my database. When I use "Debug" mode, everything is ok and work correctly. What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what type of database are you using? mdf-file.. SQL Server... maybe it will help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410407%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Try searching on the actual error message.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Are there any differences in between your `Web.Debug.config` and `Web.Release.config` files (connection strings)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke No, connection strings are the same

Comment: @EdiG. Thanks a lot. This instruction helped me to get rid of this problem. In the Properties of my website I changed "Only files needed to run this application" option on "All project files".

Comment: @emdroof your welcome. I had the same problem as i started.. :)